# Runtime error when saving mail to local disk using SenderName property

Tags: vba, outlook, runtime-error

I created a macro to back up mails which I select.

This works for one mail, but when I select a different mail in the same Outlook session I get the following error:

> Error -2147286788 (800300fc) during execution: The operation failed.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub OpslaanMails()
    Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dtDate As Date
    Dim sName, sTime As String
    sPath = "A:\Backup\"
    For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If objItem.MessageClass = "IPM.Note" Then
            Set oMail = objItem
            sName = oMail.SenderName
            sTime = oMail.ReceivedTime
            dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
            sName = sName & " " & Format(dtDate, "dd-mm-yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
              vbUseSystem) & "   " & Format(dtDate, "hh-nn-ss", _
              vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem)
            tName = Replace(sName, ":", ";")
            oMail.SaveAs sPath & tName & ".msg", olMsg
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

When I use `sName = oMail.Subject` I can select as many messages as I want and it works, but not with `oMail.SenderName`.

When I hit Debug, it fails on: `oMail.SaveAs sPath & tName & ".msg", olMsg`.

I tried commenting out `tName = Replace(sName, ":", ";")`

and changed

```
oMail.SaveAs sPath & tName & ".msg", olMsg
```

to

```
Mail.SaveAs sPath & sName & ".msg", olMsg
```

I tried declaring `oMail as Object`, but that doesn't change anything.

Adding multiple Replaces to handle the characters that aren't allowed is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `STG_E_INVALIDNAME`, whcih means the file name you pass to `SaveAs` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it. I changed `sName = oMail.SenderName` to `sName = oMail.SenderEmailAddress` and removed every Replace function. Voila, it works now!